# Variable within an expect file

Tags: linux, expect

I have an expect file that looks like this.  I invoke the script using

```
expect myfile.exp
```

I want to be able to send a value of 1,2,3 or 4.  Is there a notion of variable within the expect file?

```
expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "1\r"
expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
# This prompt can take values 1, 2, 3 or 4
send -s -- "1\r"
# I want to replace "1\r" above with one of the 4 possible values at runtime
expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "1\r"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this to be interactive? So that the script requests input from the user or does it need to be dependant on some value it receives?

Request user input:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/9781565920903/handling-a-process-and-a-user/the_expect_user_command

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use command line arguments

```
expect -f myfile.exp 2 3 1
```

Here 2 is the argument being passed.  The arguments are processed as follows in the exp file

```
set var1 [lrange $argv 0 0]
set var2 [lrange $argv 1 1]
set var3 [lrange $argv 2 2]
expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "1\r"
expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
# This prompt can take values 1, 2, 3 or 4
# Original code 
# send -s -- "1\r"

# Modified code
send -s -- "${var3}\r"

expect -exact "> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "1\r"
```

Comment: Rather than `[lrange $argv 0 0]` you should just use `[lindex $argv 0]` etc.